# Make :edit {file} use current directory during :Explore

Tags: filesystem, working-directory, netrw

I often use `:Ex` or `:Sex` to explore the filesystem from an opened file directory, or just invoke vim passing a directory to start exploring the filesystem and then opening a file.

In any case, while navigating the directory tree, using the `:edit {file}` command to open new files always takes paths relative to the current directory from which vim was executed; so:

```
~# vim .
-> navigate to Development/
-> open a file
:e <tab> will complete path from home dir
```

or:

```
~# vim Development/
-> open a file
:Sex
:e <tab> will complete paths from Development/
```

is it possible (automagically or with a command) to change vim current working directory to the current selected directory while navigating the filesystem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible by setting the netrw configuration variable `g:netrw_keepdir` to 0  (default is 1).
To make it permanent, add in the .vimrc file this line:

```
let g:netrw_keepdir=0
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, vim has a `:cd` command, which either prints the current directory or changes the current directory.  In the help is this - note the last lines:

```
:cd[!] {path}           Change the current directory to {path}.
                        If {path} is relative, it is searched for in the
                        directories listed in |'cdpath'|.
                        Does not change the meaning of an already opened file,
                        because its full path name is remembered.  Files from
                        the |arglist| may change though!
                        On MS-DOS this also changes the active drive.
                        To change to the directory of the current file: >
                                :cd %:h
```

As noted at the top of the help for `:cd`, this affects vim's working directory, not just what `:Ex` returns to or internal commands use, so external commands will also use the new location.

Comment: Is there a "directory-changed"-like event, while navigatin, which I could bind an autocommand to? Also, does it only work after opening a file?

Comment: @guido Not that I know of, but the other two answers seem like a possibility for automatic changing

Answer (score 7):

I set the following two options to ensure that Vim's current working directory is always the same as the current buffer's.

```
set autochdir                   " Changes the cwd to the directory of the current
                                " buffer whenever you switch buffers.
set browsedir=current           " Make the file browser always open the current
                                " directory.
```

Comment: The second command does it; the first will change directory also when opening a file with `vim path/to/file` which I don't want.

Comment: @guido I don't understand how setting only the `browsedir` setting affects the behaviour you're describing. That setting affects what directory the GUI file browser opens, not what directory is used for command-line completion.

Comment: @Rich you perfectly right; I forgot to delete `let g:netrw_keepdir=0` from my vimrc before testing this!