# Switching to the local directory after loading a file?

Tags: autocmd, invocation, gvim, working-directory

When running `gvim` by double clicking with a file in a graphical file manager, like nautilus, the vim instance is called with a strange current directory (seems root sometime, but I am not sure). This has the effect that file name completion (`C-x C-f`) is, well, not so useful.

I have a map that solve this:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F3> :lchdir %:p:h <CR>
```

so that I can hit `F3` and I am done. I was trying to make it happens automatically whenever I start editing, so I tried:

```
autocmd FileReadPost *.tex :lchdir %:p:h <CR>
```

and with `BufReadPost` too, but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

*Notice*: Although `set autochdir` is working, it is doing this globally; in the help there is a scary notice:

> Note: When this option is on some plugins may not work.

So it would be nice to be able to select for which buffers I want to do it, and not setting it globally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make :edit {file} use current directory during :Explore](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/631/make-edit-file-use-current-directory-during-explore)

Comment: @muru I'm not sure this is a duplicate ... The problem (having a strange cwd) should not occur at all in the first place, and netrw isn't involved here...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker alright.. So should I post `autochdir` as an answer?

Comment: @muru yes (good spotting!) , because I just tested it and it works. Although it would be nice to know why the `autocmd` did not work; what if I'd like to have it enabled only for `*.tex` files for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just installed nautilus, and it seems the current working directory is always set to the directory nautilus was started from (ie. Vim inherits nautilus' working directory).

This is a problem in nautilus (IMHO), and not Vim. When nautilus starts a new process (Vim) it can set the working directory, but doesn't. If I check `/proc/22656/cwd` it's set to `/home/martin`.

I also have space-fm installed, and if I open the same file in that, `/proc/22803/cwd` is set to `/home/martin/code` (where I would expect it to be).

---

So, now we know what the problem is, let's look at your autocmd:

> ```
> autocmd FileReadPost * :lchdir %:p:h <CR>
> ```

The `FileReadPost` does something different from what you expect, from `:help FileReadPost`:

> After reading a file with a ":read" command.

But that's not what we're doing; when you open a file Vim doesn't use `:read`. What you want to use instead, is `BufReadPost`, from `:help BufReadPost`.

> When starting to edit a new buffer

In Vi & Vim, when you think "file", or *usually* (though not always) want to think "buffer".

So this is what you want to use. You also don't need the `<CR>` here; that's just for key mappings (not autocmd)

So a working solution would be:

```
autocmd BufReadPost * :lchdir %:p:h
```

---

**But wait, there's more!**

Vim has the `autochdir` option which does the same thing! From `:help autochdir`:

> When on, Vim will change the current working directory whenever you
>           open a file, switch buffers, delete a buffer or open/close a window.
>           It will change to the directory containing the file which was opened
>           or selected.
>           Note: When this option is on some plugins may not work.

The note about plugins not working also applies to the autocmd.

Comment: Neither `BufReadPost` nor `BufWinEnter` (as suggested by  @muru) work.  `set autochdir` do work, but only globally. (BTW, I too think it's a bug/misfeature of Nautilus. Just searching a workaround)

Comment: @Rmano Hmm, using `BufReadPost` works for me (tested it, in Nautilus); perhaps there is another autocmd in that's interfering? You can try starting Vim with blank vimrc file except for this one line. You can also replace the `lchdir` with `echoerr(expand("%:p:h"))` to show an "error" with the file path (this is useful for debugging).

Comment: Ok. Found it. If I call `gvim /home/romano/path/file.tex` it works, but if I call (as is doing my default action) `exec gvim --servername desktop_0 --remote-tab-silent /home/romano/path/file.tex` it does not work (`desktop_0` is automatically generated for the current desktop). Now I am really puzzled.

Comment: @Rmano Hm, it seems autocmd works different when using `--remote`? Not sure ... Need to test more ...

Comment: Ok, marking this as answered --- and posting another question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try the autodir setting in vimrc.

```
set autochdir
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the `ReadPost` events aren't applicable since the documentation describes them as related to the `:read` command. You could try the `Enter` events, either `BufEnter` or `BufWinEnter`. For example:

```
autocmd BufWinEnter *.tex  lchdir %:p:h
```