# Different autocmd behavior when using --remote-tab-silent?

Tags: autocmd, tabbed-user-interface, clientserver

This question is a follow-up to [Switching to the local directory after loading a file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/switching-to-the-local-directory-after-loading-a-file)

I have the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *.tex lchdir %:p:h
```

with the intent of setting the current directory to the same as the edited file for `*.tex` files, *without* setting the global `autochdir`.

It works if I call:

```
 gvim /home/romano/education/IntroEle-SAP-135/Lab-T1/LabTestExample.tex
```

Look at the full filename in status line here:

[image: Working autocmd lchdir]

But it **does not** work if I call:

```
gvim --servername desktop_0 --remote-tab-silent /home/romano/education/IntroEle-SAP-135/Lab-T1/LabTestExample.tex
```

Screenshot:

[image: Not working autocmd]

(the culprit seems to be the `--remote-tab-silent` switch). How can I correct this so that the `autocmd` works in the two cases?

Comment: [Four years old and no responses...](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/8DZdu57h-3k)

Comment: So seems a bug... where is the main bug report site for vim? Searched here http://www.vim.org/ but just found mailing lists...

Comment: Looking around in that mailing list, I think it's on Google Code: https://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/list

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug, or expected behaviour (but it could very well be one!) I need to carefuly read the remote server & autocmd pages to be sure... You can use `:help bug-reports` for information on how to report them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a half workaround. The trick is that if you use `--remote-send` instead of `--remote` you can make all the `autocmd` working.

So I subsituted

```
gvim --servername $desktop --remote-tab-silent "$file"
```

with

```
 gvim --servername $desktop --remote-send "<ESC>:tabe $file<CR><CR>"
```

...and the `autocmd` works now. `<ESC>` is needed because the instance can be in input mode (annoyingly beeps if not) and the double `<CR>` is needed because otherwise vim is asking me to press a key --- I do not know why. Now, this **do not work** if `$file` has spaces in it; but this is OT here I think. Or [maybe another question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-to-escape-a-whole-string-in-a-command).

Now, there is no `--remote-send-silent` option do my script for double clicking on a file in nautilus and have it opened in the existing desktop-local gvim instance or open a new one has got a bit more complex (if anyone want to see it I can post it here, but it seems a bit OT).

Comment: I had this problem too and worked around it by using `BufReadPost,BufEnter,BufWinEnter`, but it still appeared sometimes. Thanks to this note on `--remote-send` I was able to find a reason of such behaviour, [see this vim-dev post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/2nrIOoiJzVU). So maybe it will be fixed in Vim soon. Another temporary half workaround is to set `'autochdir'` option, if you're fine with changing directory for all filetypes.

Comment: @xaizek thanks --- this is clearly the case for the behavior descried here. I have a workaround in the [linked post](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-to-escape-a-whole-string-in-a-command) --- I do not like `autochdir` for all files (even for TeX files, I do want the switch only for `.tex`, not for example `.sty`...)

Comment: The patch has been accepted as [7.4.678](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/WLaddu-dXCQ).