# How to escape a whole string in a : command?

Tags: command-line

Let's see. I have a `gvim` running and I want open a file, respecting the `autocmd`s ([which rules out `--remote-tab`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2066/different-autocmd-behavior-when-using-remote-tab-silent)).

Now I know I can do (basically, with some tweak):

```
gvim --remote-send ":tabe my_file<CR>"
```

which works. But if a file has spaces or strange chars in it, I have to do the following:

```
gvim --remote-send ":tabe my\\ file<CR>"
```

(the double `\\` is because one of them is eaten by the shell; this is equivalent to manually type

```
`:tabe my\ file`
```

in `vim` and it works). Now, I can find a way to create that string in the shell or whatever, but I hoped I could "globally quote" the string in the ":tabe" command, like

```
 gvim --remote-send ":tabe 'my file'<CR>"
```

or

```
 gvim --remote-send ":tabe \"my file\"<CR>"
```

--- this is equivalent to writing directly in the vim command line `:tabe "my file"`; it seems it is not working. I can explicitly quote all space in the string with the shell, doing something like

```
# <ESC> because the gvim instance can be in a mode different from normal
# the double CR: do not ask. 
# the argument MUST be a full path
file="$(readlink -f "$@")"
fileq="$(echo "$file" |  awk '{gsub(/ /,"\\\ ")}1')" # quote spaces FIXME add other chars
exec gvim 2>/dev/null --servername $desktop --remote-send "<ESC>:tabe $fileq <CR><CR>"
```

but it works just for spaces and not other special chars like tabs and `"` (nor newlines, but if you have newlines in your file names you deserve it!).

**The question**:

Independently on the particular shell, with which I will deal after :-), is there a way *when directly typing* in the vim `tabe:` line to globally quote a filename without going to quote the "strange" chars one by one?

Comment: Seems highly shell dependent. `gvim --remote-send ':tabe foo\ bar.txt<CR>'` worked for me on bash and zsh. And the quotes seem to matter too. If I use `"` internally, it didn't work, but `'` did: `gvim --remote-send ":tabe 'foo bar.txt'<CR>"`

Comment: Hmmm... `gvim --remote-send ":tabe 'f s.txt'<CR>"` didn't work for me, nor writing `:tabe 'f s.txt'` in vim, I got `E77: Too many files names`.

Comment: I jumped the gun a bit. For me, a tab opens alright, but the filename is `'foo bar.txt'`, with the quotes. But a single backslash still works, as does `foo="f\ s.txt" gvim --remote-send ":tabe $foo<CR>"`.

Comment: @muru yep I have `fileq="$(echo "$file" |  awk '{gsub(/ /,"\\\ ")}1')"` and `gvim --servername $desktop --remote-send "<ESC>:tabe $fileq <CR><CR>"
` which works, but just for spaces...

Comment: Wouldn't `gvim --servername $desktop --remote-send "<ESC>:tabe ${file// /\\ }<CR>"` be simpler?

Comment: @muru probably yes. Although working just for spaces again...

Comment: I have one twisted idea: Keep a fixed file open in GVim, write your filename to that file, have Vim autoreload its contents and open any new lines in new tabs.

Comment: Have you tried replacing spaces with `<Space>`? Since `<Esc>` and `<Cr>` is captured by Vim and interpreted correctly maybe `<Space>` would too

Comment: @Sukima -- the problem is that I would like a way to quote *the whole string* without having to substitute anything. The solution for spaces works, but it's not generic (what about `"`, or other special chars?)

Comment: Would the `shellescape` function be helpful?

Comment: Keep in mind that `:edit` (and its variants) doesn't accept a quoted filename. All special characters need to be individually escaped. So, `:edit "foo bar.txt"` won't work; you need `:edit foo\ bar.txt`. That said, something like `:execute 'tabedit' escape('$file', ' ')` might be on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general info, and thanks to all the comments, this is the script I use to have an "open in a tab on the gvim on this desktop" script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
#
# this is convoluted because it has to finish in an exec to keep the DM happy
# remember to set StartupNotify=false in the .desktop file
#
desktop=desktop_$(xprop -root -notype  _NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP | perl -pe 's/.*?= (\d+)/$1/')

if ! vim --serverlist | grep -iq $desktop; then #we need to start the server
    if [ $# != 0 ]; then 
        exec gvim 2>/dev/null --servername $desktop "$@"
    else
        exec gvim 2>/dev/null --servername $desktop  #no files 
    fi
fi
# the only case here is if we need to open a tab in an existing server
if [ $# != 0 ]; then  
        # Do not use --remote-tab, see http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2066/different-autocmd-behavior-when-using-remote-tab-silent
        # <ESC> because the gvim instance can be in a mode different from normal
        # the double CR: do not ask. 
        # the argument MUST be a full path
        file="$(readlink -f "$@")"
        #fileq="$(echo "$file" |  awk '{gsub(/ /,"\\\ ")}1')" # quote spaces FIXME add other chars
        fileq=${file// /\\ } # quote spaces FIXME add other chars
        exec gvim 2>/dev/null --servername $desktop --remote-send "<ESC>:tabe $fileq <CR><CR>"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

What i've managed to send to Vim is:
`'<C-\\><C-N>:1wincmd<C-q>x20w<CR>'`
Where space is defined as x20 which means insert hex$20.